# HTML Script for CSV file not writing data directly - Swapping < > for &lt and &gt and not keeping html

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I'm currently trying to script a CSV table into a webpage chart in HTML.

This script works where it takes a 'partner_dash.csv' within the web DIR and puts the contents of the CSV.

At the same time, i'm trying to format some HTML HREF links within (or buttons etc) for simplicity as I can write this via python and throw in the code in the CSV without needing to modify webpages.

When doing so, the script is parsing the < > as &lt and &gt (less than, greater than) instead of HTML <>.

Is there a way to have it not do this and read the CSV 'as is' without that translation? Is this something that I'd need to escape somehow?

Example CSV:

```
<a href="partner_client/test_partner">Test Partner</a>, 8,2,0,0,10
```

What appears on the element(Note the < > being translated:
[image]

And therefore in the table of:
[image]

Script:

```html
        <script>
        var csv_array = ["partner_dash.csv"];
        $(function() {
            
            $(csv_array).each(function(){
                Papa.parse(this.toString(), {
                    download: true,
                    complete: function(results) {
                        console.log("Remote file parsed!", results.data);
                        $.each(results.data, function(i, el) {
                            var row = $("<tr/>");
                            row.append($("<td/> ").text());
                            $.each(el, function(j, cell) {
                                if (cell !== "")
                                    row.append($(" <td/>").text(cell));
                            });
                            $("tbody").append(row);
                        });
                    }
                });
    
            })
    
        }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: Although @mplungjan is correct, you should use `html()` instead of `text()`, I would try to avoid having HTML inside the CSV. This could allow a malicious actor to embed a dangerous script directly in to your page unless you are also filtering/sanitising what is coming from the CSV.